# Why is function pattern matching not working, but explicit pattern matching is?

Tags: ocaml

I wrote a function that take a number, and returns the negative version of that number. If the passed number is negative, it will simply return the number. `make_negative :: int -> int`.

My first implementation was as follows:

```ml
let make_negative x =
  match x with
  | 0 -> 0
  | y when y < 0 -> y
  | y when y > 0 -> -y
```

When I see this pattern, I like to think that I can replace it with the following:

```ml
let make_negative_two =
  | 0 -> 0
  | x when x < 0 -> x
  | x when x > 0 -> -x;;
```

However, I see the following error: `syntax error: expecting expr.`

Comment: you are missing `function` after `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with OCaml, in fact your post is the first I've heard of it, so my answer may be a bit naive.

But looking at your second solution, and cross referencing the "learn" documentation, something stood out.

The second solution, the one causing the syntax  error, seems to be malformed, as in it is an incomplete expression. I'm not familiar with the language terminology of OCaml, but the following does pass, from a syntax checker I found online.

```
let make_negative_two = function
  | 0 -> 0
  | x when x < 0 -> x
  | x when x > 0 -> -x;;
```

If that works, great!

To my mind the "function" keyword, completes the expression.

---

I referenced https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/ocaml-class/pattern-matching.html, https://ocaml.org/problems and https://try.ocamlpro.com to compose this response

Comment: Completely forgot about the function keyword! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax error, it's a rather common mistake to think branching should be done with a `match` (or any equivalent). That usage is only for `if` expressions / statements. So the proper way to write your function would be

```ml
let make_negative_three x =
  if x < 0 then x else -x
```

Pattern matching should be reserved for deconstruction.

---

Also note (even though it's not directly related to the problem) that the cons function, and the typing notation in OCaml and in Haskell are inverted. That is, you would note `make_negative_three : int -> int`, not `make_negative_three :: int -> int`, which would mean in OCaml what the first version would mean in Haskell.

Comment: I can't help but feel this is more of a comment than an answer, especially given that it doesn't actually answer the core question. The very existence of `when` in the language suggests that your assertion that pattern-matching cannot be used for conditional branching is more an expression of personal opinion about what _should_ be done than what actually _can_ be done.

Comment: @Chris it's not entirely false, but it was too long for a comment and I felt it could still be useful to a beginner. As for `when`, branching is just a subcase of pattern matching; if you *only* do branching, you should use a dedicated branching syntax. And, indeed, this is not about what you *can* do, but about what you *should* do. It's clear that this is an opinion, but I'm not sure whether this is an "official" position of the OCaml language or not. I was taught OCaml with this being the idiomatic way of writing OCaml, but I haven't verified it.

Comment: Also, `let make_negative_three x = -(abs x)` :)

Comment: @Chris yes :) of course, the point was not to write the shortest and / or *most* idiomatic function, but how to transform a branching-only pattern match into an if statement.